# How to throw this exception in a test?

Tags: testing, exception, clojure

I am trying to test a `java.sql.SQLException` handler which unwraps the exceptions like below. However I'm not sure how I would throw this exception in a test.

```
(-> e 
    (.getNextException) 
    (.getMessage) 
    (.startsWith "ERROR: duplicate key value"))
```

current mock `(.getNextException)` returns nil on this:

```
(throw (SQLException. "ERROR: duplicate key value"))
```

Comment: Please add your code to the question.

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
(throw (doto (SQLException. "Top-level exception") 
             (.setNextException (SQLException. "ERROR: duplicate key value"))))
```